Pairwise comparison of multiple fields in Pyspark dataframes
I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like the one below.
key_field   fieldA   fieldB   fieldC
ddd         A1       B1       C1
ddd         A2       B2       C2
ddd         A2       B2       C2
eee         A1       B1       C1
eee         A3       B3       C3

The goal is to group by key_field (but mapping them to numbers for easier pairwise comparison via a loop later), and store unique groups of < fieldA,fieldB,fieldC > by the key_field. And then compare the groups of < fieldA,fieldB,fieldC > belonging to 2 key_field to see if there is any common group (i.e. intersection).
So in this example, I would have
1: (A1,B1,C1), (A2,B2,C2)  <-- key_field: ddd mapped to 1
2: (A1,B1,C1), (A3,B3,C3)  <-- key_field: eee mapped to 2

1 and 2 have the common (A1,B1,C1).
I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.
Initially, I thought a dictionary of sets could be used to store the data, and then I could iterate through the dictionary keys and compare the sets pairwise.
So far, I have created a list out of the unique key_field values, so that I can use the item's index as the dictionary key when storing the group < fieldA,fieldB,fieldC >.
key_list = list(df.select(df.key_field).distinct().toPandas()["key_field"])
Then I was thinking I could create the dictionary with something like
new_dict[key_list.index("key_field")].append((df.fieldA, df.fieldB, df.fieldC))
by iterating through the dataframe row by row. But I'm not sure how this should be done, or even if this is the best way to do it.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how I can ultimately do a pairwise comparison between the groups of < fieldA,fieldB,fieldC > belonging to each key_field.

It is not clear to me what output you are looking for.  you want intersection of the collection?  Could you state the final output in table format and explain the logic you want to derive it?
